# Filtering/searching for entries by category in the control panel

Tags: categories, control-panel

Is there any way of filtering by category in the control panel entries list?

Likewise, is there for an "entries" field (like how Playa lets you filter by channel, category)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can via the search box:

```
myCategoriesField:"some category title"
```

See http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching for details on the syntax.

We do plan on making it possible to add category/tag filters to the element indexes though, including the modal selection windows.

---

**Update:** You can add a list of categories to the Entries page sidebar using the [Category Sources](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CategorySources) plugin.

Comment: Is this new feature slated for 2.2?

Comment: We don’t have a specific release in mind for it yet.

Comment: This is huge for me. I have channels with hundreds of entries that don't have any logical order to them. My content editors are going to struggle with a search syntax. Similarly for assets. I don't want to use folders and sub-folders as I think it is the wrong way to go. My front end allows for category filtering so it would be great to provide the ability to have this in the CP. I do have a special front end page that connects content editors directly to the entry editing page, but they have to go out to that page and back in again.

Comment: @JackMcKenzie Just updated this answer with a link to [Category Sources](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CategorySources), a plugin that adds categories to the Entries page sidebar.