# Filtering lists of entries in the control panel by entry type

Tags: entries, control-panel, filtering

I’m aware of [Filtering/searching for entries by category in the control panel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/filtering-searching-for-entries-by-category-in-the-control-panel), but that doesn’t work for:

```
entryType:"String"
```

…where ‘String’ is the entry type `name` or `handle`, or…

```
typeId:Int
```

…where `Int` is the `entries` table’s `typeId` number.

Is something like this possible with some other syntax?

I can add `Entry Type` to the list scope and sort by it, but that’s not what I’m hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-the box, Craft doesn't offer such filters, but adding them isn't that hard [using a module](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/custom-module-events).

You need to listen to 2 events:

- [`\craft\elements\Entry::EVENT_REGISTER_SEARCHABLE_ATTRIBUTES`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#events): to add searchable attributes (the prefix you use in the search field, before the colon)
- [`\craft\elements\Entry::EVENT_DEFINE_KEYWORDS`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#events): to set the value your custom searchable field

Something like this should work (although I haven't tested):

```
Event::on(
    \craft\elements\Entry::class,
    \craft\base\Element::EVENT_REGISTER_SEARCHABLE_ATTRIBUTES,
    function(\craft\events\RegisterElementSearchableAttributesEvent $event) {
        $event->attributes[] = 'entryType';
        $event->attributes[] = 'typeId';
    }
);

Event::on(
    \craft\elements\Entry::class,
    \craft\base\Element::EVENT_DEFINE_KEYWORDS,
    function (\craft\events\DefineAttributeKeywordsEvent $event) {
        /** @var \craft\elements\Entry $entry */
        $entry = $event->sender;

        if ($event->attribute === 'entryType') {
            $event->keywords = $entry->type->handle;
        } elseif ($event->attribute === 'typeId') {
            $event->keywords = $entry->type->id;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'll look into that.